# Stamina Bar refuses to go back up

Tags: c#, unity

I am creating a very simple script for my stamina bar to go down when I press M, but when I am not pressing M, for the bar to go back up slowly back to 100.The bar goes down fine when I press M, however, while the bar does go down, it refuses to go back up.

Attached is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class StaminaBar : MonoBehaviour {
    public Scrollbar StaminaGUIBar;
    public float Stamina;

    void Start()
    {
        Stamina = 100;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(Stamina);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.M))
        {
            Stamina -= 5;
            StaminaGUIBar.size = Stamina /100f;
            Refuel();
        }
    }

    public void Refuel()
    {
        while (Stamina < 100)
        {
            Stamina += 5f;
            StaminaGUIBar.size = Stamina * 100f;

            if (Stamina >= 100)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any Ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Refuel` is only being called when M is down. Additionally, your while loop will be run in a single shot, and so will fail to bring the fuel back "slowly" anyway. A similar problem exists with your rate of depletion, as it will only run over 20 frames (.33 seconds @ 60FPS) before it's fully depleted.  Maybe you want something like this?

```
public class StaminaBar : MonoBehaviour {
    public Scrollbar StaminaGUIBar;
    public float Stamina;

    void Start()
    {
        Stamina = 100f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(Stamina);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.M))
        {
            // deplete Stamina at a rate of 5 units per second
            Stamina -= 5f * Time.deltaTime;
            StaminaGUIBar.size = Stamina / 100f;
        }
        else if(Stamina < 100f)
        {
            Refuel();
        }
    }

    public void Refuel()
    {
        Stamina = Mathf.Min(100f, Stamina + 5f * Time.deltaTime);
        StaminaGUIBar.size = Stamina / 100f;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have probably a typo there: `1.0f` instead of `100.0f`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your call to Refuel() is in the wrong place. It's currently in the if statement so your only refilling while M is held down.